# malloc and pointer code demonstration

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, mergesort

I don't have enough knowledge about pointer and malloc! I tried to read books but did't got it clearly and I can't understood these lines of code:

```
L = (int*)malloc(mid*sizeof(int));
R = (int*)malloc((n- mid)*sizeof(int));
```

What value actually `L` and `R` having?

```
for(i = 0;i<mid;i++) L[i] = A[i]; 
for(i = mid;i<n;i++) R[i-mid] = A[i];
```

and in for loop I see L and R having index no? I'm confused How come `L and R acting as array`.

Full Code:

```
void MergeSort(int *A,int n) {
    int mid,i, *L, *R;
    if(n < 2) return; // base condition. If the array has less than two element, do nothing.

    mid = n/2;  // find the mid index.

    // create left and right subarrays
    // mid elements (from index 0 till mid-1) should be part of left sub-array
    // and (n-mid) elements (from mid to n-1) will be part of right sub-array
    L = (int*)malloc(mid*sizeof(int));
    R = (int*)malloc((n- mid)*sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0;i<mid;i++) L[i] = A[i]; // creating left subarray
    for(i = mid;i<n;i++) R[i-mid] = A[i]; // creating right subarray

    MergeSort(L,mid);  // sorting the left subarray
    MergeSort(R,n-mid);  // sorting the right subarray
    Merge(A,L,mid,R,n-mid);  // Merging L and R into A as sorted list.
        free(L);
        free(R);
}
```

Comment: A *pointer* is nothing but a variable that holds the *address of* something else as its value, instead of an *immediate value* like `5`. For example `int a = 5;` creates the variable `a` which holds the immediate value `5`. Now `int *b = &a;` creates the integer *pointer* `b` that holds the address of `a` as its value. `b` is a pointer to `a`. Also, Do *NOT* cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) for thorough explanation.

Comment: In other words, `L = malloc (mid * sizeof *L);` is all that is needed to allocate storage for `mid` integers.

Comment: *"I tried to read books but did't got it clearly"* -- what books are you reading?  What you ask are fundamental questions, and it is important that you read a good textbook to understand the concepts.  Try Kernighan and Ritchie's "The C programming Language"

Comment: I read deitel C 6th edition. There there the writer didn't show any example with pointer like in this code Im facing! I read pointer chapter! From the book. Uou can have a look or can suggest me a good book. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is really just the address of a memory location.

The value of a pointer variable is the address the pointer is pointing to.

[The `malloc` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) allocates a chunk of bytes somewhere in memory (where that memory is located is irrelevant). It returns a pointer to the first byte of that memory.

---

A little more visually a pointer and what it points to could be seen as this:

```
+---------+      +------------+
| pointer | ---> | Memory ... |
+---------+      +------------+
```

You could also see the memory returned by `malloc` as an array. Taking parts of the code from your example, if `mid` is `5` then you have something like this:

```
+---+      +------+------+------+------+------+------+
| L | ---> [ L[0] | L[1] | L[2] | L[3] | L[4] | .... |
+---+      +------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

That is, the variable `L` points to the first element (`L[0]`) in the allocated "array".

Do note that there is really no end to the "array" allocated by `malloc`. C doesn't have any bounds checking, and the compiler will not give you any error or warning for using an index that is out of bounds (for example `L[5]` using out example above). It will lead to *undefined behavior* and possibly crashes or weird behavior, but you can still access or even write to that element.

Also note that taking the size of a pointer with the `sizeof` operator will not return the size of the memory it points to, but the size of the pointer itself. For example doing `sizeof L` will not return `mid` or `mid * sizeof(int)`. It will return the size of the pointer variable `L`, which is typically `4` or `8` depending on if you're on a 32 or 64 bit system.

Answer (score 0):

> What value actually L and R having?

They hold the addresses of the start of the memory blocks that `malloc` just allocated for us.

You can think of `malloc` as creating a new variable somewhere (it doesn't have name); since we called `malloc` twice it created two, and `L` and `R` point to them. You can't use those "variables" directly because they don't have names, but you can use `*L` and `*R`.

> and in for loop I see L and R having index no? I'm confused How come L and R acting as array.

In C, `a[b]` is short for `*(a + b)`. So `L[i]` is short for `*(L + i)`.

Answer (score 0):

malloc() returns pointer(i.e memory address) to the starting pointing of the block you have asked for. so L and R are addresses to two blocks which here is used to store the left half and right half of the array A. 
Since the addresses are type-casted to integers pointers, you are now looking at that memory block as an integer array. i.e if you have asked for 40 bytes and if you have type-casted the address returned by malloc() as (int *) then you are looking at an array of 10 integers (assuming an integer is 4 bytes in size). 
Now since you have the starting address say L which points to first integer, you can now traverse the array using simple pointer manipulation. L[i] is same as *(L+i) which is corresponds to ith integer in the array L.